# How to determine if fs.createWriteSteam completes successfully?

Tags: node.js

I'm using a [write stream](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createwritestream_path_options) to write a file. The "finish" and "close" events fire even if the file isn't fully written yet, if I abort the input stream.

How can I tell if it's fully complete?

```
var Http = require('http');
var FileSystem = require('fs');

Http.createServer(function (req, resp) {
    var destFileStream = FileSystem.createWriteStream('testfile');

    destFileStream.on('finish', function () {
        // was the write successful or not?
    });

    req.pipe(destFileStream);
});
```

Comment: How are you aborting the input stream? Please show us some code :)

Comment: @Ben By pressing the "refresh" button in my browser. It's a file upload. There's quite a lot of code here.... I'll pull out a snippet.

Comment: you can use _end_ event on a writeble stream and if it successfully finished your callback will be fired

Answer (score 0):

The write steam should emit an event when/if an error occurs, this can be used to assume it was successful and wrote without problems.

```
destFileStream.on('err', function(err){
    console.log(err);
})
```

This can be used to check if the files was not written correctly.

Comment: No error occurs. There's no permission error or anything, the request stream just stops sending data.